# Trying to run heroku locally and get a error 'vendor' is not a command

Tags: php, heroku, path, composer-php, vendor

I am trying to run heroku locally using the command

```
heroku local
```

However, it returns:

```
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
[DONE] Killing all proccess with signal null
Exited with exit code 1
```

I am using Heroku PHP within Windows 7

In my `PATH` environmental variable, I have both:
`./vendor/bin` and `C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`

(The last one is an empty folder)

I searched for anything similar but I couldn't find.
Any thoughts on it?

Thanks in advance

**Update**

The error was in my Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

Then I change all slashes to backslashes ():

```
web: vendor\bin\heroku-php-apache2 public\
```

Now its working but I am getting this error:

```
../heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/bin/heroku-php-apache2: line 196: php-fpm: command not found
This program requires PHP 5.5.11 or newer; check your 'php-fpm' command.
```

I think there is something wrong related to my composer.

The source file for `heroku-php-apache2` can be found [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/heroku-php-apache2).
The line 196 is presented below.

```
196: { php-fpm -n -v | php -n -r 'exit((int)version_compare(preg_replace("#PHP (\S+) \(fpm-fcgi\).+$#sm", "\\1", file_get_contents("php://stdin")), "5.5.11", "<"));'; } || { echo "This program requires PHP 5.5.11 or newer; check your 'php-fpm' command." >&2; exit 1; }
```

My composer.json file is:

```
{
  "require" : {
    "ext-mcrypt": "*",
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0",
    "google/apiclient": "2.0"  
  },
  "require-dev": {
        "mashape/unirest-php": "3.*",
        "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
    }
}
```

I tried to specific `require` php in composer.json but it didn't changed. Any thoughts on that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `vendor` _shouldn't_ be a command. Do you know why `heroku local` is trying to run it? Nothing in your question sheds any light on that.

Comment: Do you have a `Procfile`?

Comment: @Chris just checked the Procfile and it is exactly what you mentioned: `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/` It is trying to read the first line as a command. How can a I change it? As you can imagine, I am new to heroku and development in general. Thank you

Comment: Just to clarify, this procfile was generated accordingly to the tutorials in the Heroku website in order to create a public folder.

Comment: That actually looks okay to me, Jean Phelippe. It's trying to run `heroku-php-apache2`, located in the `vendor/bin/` directory. There are no spaces in that line, e.g. `web: vendor /bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/`?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the reply. Actually there is no space. I changed all slashes to backslashes (\) and the command worked. However now I am getting the error: `../bin/heroku-php-apache2: line 196: php-fpm: command not found`. It's not finding this command `php-fpm`. You can check the heroku-php-apache2 source at https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/heroku-php-apache2 I update the question with my composer.

Answer (score 1):

Years later, I've faced this same issue.

Fixed by removing `vendor/` and running `composer install` again.

Then I've faced the same `php-fpm` error and to fix that I created a symbolic link from `/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4 -> /usr/sbin/php-fpm`.

Hope that becomes helpful to orthers in the future!